# Misspelling my name on my mathematical publications

Tags: soft-question, journals

Perpetuating a mistake by my thesis advisor, I misspelt my name on my mathematical publications so far -- any advice on what to do?

As it happens, my thesis advisor, with whom I co-authored [my first paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1364.20007), 
misspelt my last name on that paper. He then approved the page proofs. For this reason, on that paper, my name reads 
Leyli Jafari Taghvasani instead of Leyli Jafari Taghvastani.

In the sequel, in order to have all my publications under the same name, he advised me to stick
to the wrong spelling of my name, and publish all my papers under the name Leyli Jafari Taghvasani
instead of Leyli Jafari Taghvastani. I followed his advice, and published already
some more papers under my misspelt name: [JafariTaghvasaniZarrin2017](https://dx.doi.org/10.22108/ijgt.2017.10631),
[JafariTaghvasaniZarrin2018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1406.20024), [JafariTaghvasaniMarzangZarrin2018](https://dx.doi.org/10.21136/CMJ.2018.0464-17),
[JafariTaghvasaniKohl2019](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2019.1588979).

My question is: what is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Change your name?

Comment: It may depend on the stage of your career. If you are early in your career, it may be better to start publishing with your correct name, but include all your publications on your CV, explaining there that some publications were published under a variant name. Personally, to me it does not seem right that you have to maintain an incorrect publishing name for the rest of your career because your adviser misspelt it once- but mine might be a minority opinion.

Comment: I have heard that MathSciNet devotes a great deal of effort to ensuring that publications are attributed to the right authors even when two authors have the same name, or one author goes by different names in different places.  So if you were to contact them, I am sure that they would sort it out in their database, at least.  The ArXiV also tracks authors by numeric identifiers rather than names.

Comment: I started publishing under "Yves de C##" and later mostly under "Yves C##". I changed mostly because people mess up with the first version (adding capital to "de", adding "de" in phrases where it shouldn't) so that the second version makes my life easier. However, a consequence is that typing "C##" (fully spelled of course) in MathSciNet results in a partial list (one has to click my name, then click "publications" to get the full list under both names). I'm saying this because this is what will happen if you publish under 2 names, and maybe you don't want this as long as you're applying.

Comment: What?? How does an advisor not know how to spell his own student's name?

Comment: @NikWeaver Anyone can make an error.  What I find truly bizarre is the suggestion that they should continue to mis-spell the name.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: I guess.  I make errors all the time, but it's hard for me to imagine misspelling my own student's name on a paper.

Comment: @NikWeaver : I am highly sensitive to misspellings myself, but I've learned that many people are not. The advisor may literally have not noticed that the name on the paper was spelled any differently from the way it was spelled elsewhere. Anyway, I side with those who say that there is no reason to continue misspelling the name just for the sake of consistency.

Comment: An advisor can misspell a student's name, this can happen for some reason (we have unequal sensibility to spelling). What's more weird is that the advisor didn't involve his student in proof checking, assuming the OP's related faithfully what happened.

Comment: @NikWeaver It's very easy to overlook such trivialities when proofreading. There's at least one single-author paper where the author's name is misspelled, not on the first page but in the header of a later page. (I know this only because I reviewed the paper for MathReviews: MR0363912 (51 #167).) As for myself, as the thesis adviser of Thiradet Jiarasuksakun, I certainly won't claim inerrancy in such matters (though I don't think I've misspelled my students' names yet).

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for Academia.Stackexchange. The issue is not a mathematical one.

Comment: @s.c why was this made Community Wiki?

Comment: @Tim The custom on MathOverflow is roughly: questions without precise mathematical answers get CW.

Comment: By the way, to all you potential advisers out there (and coauthors in general): you should *never* approve page proofs without the blessing of all authors.  Moreover, it can be a very good thing for young researchers to carefully read page proofs.

Comment: You could try contacting the journals where these were published to get an erratum/correction issued for each one.

Comment: this sort of problem pops up regularly for people with names spelled natively in a non-Latin alphabet. (Cyrillic, Hindi, Hebrew, etc), especially where there is no unique way to transliterate. (And authorities knowing better than you how to spell - e.g. at some point I had extra "t" in my family name in passport, while my father had extra "s" :-))

Comment: At some point I managed to get rid of extra "t" in the Latin spelling of my name, thanks to a friendly certified translator and the government of The Netherlands :-)

Comment: @AndreasBlass's [review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=363912) (of [Vaught - Invariant sets in topology and logic](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-82-3-269-294)) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335697/misspelling-my-name-on-my-mathematical-publications#comment838821_335697).

Answer (score 36):

People change their names for various reasons and manage to maintain the attribution of their work. Should you decide to go with the correct spelling of your name (as I would do if it were me) then you should notify MathSciNet, zbMATH, and the arXiv so they link the two names. MathSciNet at least is generally good about giving each mathematician a unique identifier, and that would help. If you make use of ORCID, then I would make sure that both names generate the same ID.

Answer (score 26):

Since you have the luxury of a double surname, there is an easy solution that avoids having to go back and correct older publications: use Leyli Jafari from now on. Spanish authors do this all the time, they have a double surname but typically only use the first in their scientific publications (one of my Iranian students also decided to drop his second surname to simplify his citation record).

Databases (Web of Science, Google Scholar) will be able to connect your older publications with author name "Leyli Jafari Taghvasani" to your new publications "Leyli Jafari" (in particular if you have a unique ORCID identifier), and colleagues who type "Leyli Jafari" in a search engine will be directed to both sets of papers.

I checked on Google Scholar that there is no other "L. Jafari", so dropping the second surname should not complicate matter in that respect (and I notice you are already following that practice here on Mathoverflow...).

But the main benefit of the ellipsis is that you will not have to explain this embarassing story that your advisor changed your name...

Answer (score 12):

I think the concern about having all your papers be listed together on professional databases like MathSciNet and ZBMath, while real, is more minor than the current answers make it seem. The key point to remember is:

**99% of people looking up your publications will use Google or another search engine to do so.**

Since search engines are extremely good at correcting these sorts of minor typos, the solution is therefore quite simple. The main things you need to do are:

1. Start publishing under your name as it is correctly spelled.
2. Set up a personal home page where you have an easily accessible and well-formatted list of publications, with links to the papers’ final versions and/or arXiv versions, and keep that home page up to date and alive (if you move institutions, set up a redirect from the older page, etc).
3. Add a small note on that page explaining that your first few papers were published with a variant spelling of your name.

Steps 1 and 2 are actually things that any early-career mathematician should do, and are much more important than fidgeting over how MathSciNet thinks your name is spelled.

The advice to contact MathSciNet and other databases and ask them to link the publications listed under the different spellings of your name is generally good, but, if you follow the steps I am suggesting, whether they will do what you are asking or not will, in my opinion, have an altogether negligible effect on your career success.

Answer (score 8):

It's worthwhile to let the people at *MathSciNet* (reachable even without a subscription via email [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/support_mail.html)) know about this, as done for example when a woman publishes under both her given name and her married name.    This is probably the most comprehensive database maintained for mathematics.

Similarly, people at *Zentralblatt* should know about this, to avoid making separate search lists.

Comment: I know at least one male mathematician who took his wife's surname upon getting married.

Comment: Remember that you can link papers under different names even in a ridiculous organization such as Thomson.

Answer (score 3):

This could be something that you will regret (in a small way) for the rest of your life. In your position, I would give serious consideration to changing back to your real name, before it's too late.